# SFML. Как сделать увеличение/уменьшение масштаба камеры на колёсико мыши?

Tags: c++, sfml

SFML. Как сделать увеличение/уменьшение масштаба камеры на колёсико мыши?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать объект класса sf::View и назначить его метод .zoom() на событие sf::Event::MouseWheelScrolled

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "EXAMPLE");
    sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 500, 500));
    window.setView(view);

    sf::RectangleShape shape1(sf::Vector2f(200, 50));
    sf::CircleShape shape2(100.f);
    shape2.setPosition(150, 150);
    shape2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseWheelScrolled && event.mouseWheelScroll.wheel == sf::Mouse::VerticalWheel)
            {

                if (event.mouseWheelScroll.delta > 0)
                    view.zoom(0.99);
                else
                    view.zoom(1.01);
                window.setView(view);
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape1);
        window.draw(shape2);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```